# Determine average of values in a column based upon a column with a unique identifier via Excel 2010

Tags: excel, aggregate, average

I am trying to determine the average of values in a column based upon a column with a unique identifier. I have included a picture for clarification.
[image: Example]

Column A represents block groups, of which there are 27 unique groups. Column E represents the year a structure was built within that block group. There are multiple instances of the same block group number in Column A and I would like to aggregate each of these block group numbers and determine the average year built for all of the structures in each of the 27 block groups.

For example, there are 18 cases of block group '240419601001' and my goal is to average the years associated with this block group number and then have that result appear in a new column.

My end goal is to take these averages and use them to fill in rows where there is no year built associated with a specific block group.

Thanks.

Comment: So, I assume you work for the tax man as an appraiser.  I don't know if I want to help you. :P

Comment: Nothing so sinister! I am but a humble social scientist, utilizing secondary data. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want AverageIf():

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"240419601001",E:E)
```

so in an empty column put this formula in row 2:

```
=IF(E2="",AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,E:E),E2)
```

Then copy and past just the values over column E.

Comment: This seems like a great starting point. I also found that utilizing the Pivot Table tool was helpful. However, I am still unsure how I would populate empty value fields (year) with these averages based on the block group they correspond to.

Comment: @EricM now I understand the problem. See edit on how to deal with it.